# pyproject.toml is not installing my package dependencies

Tags: pip, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

It is my first time working with `pyproject.toml` and I was sort of under the impression that when you list package `abc` as one of your project's dependencies, that package's dependencies would also be installed even though they are not explicitly listed.

This is my current `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "setuptools-scm"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "boop"
readme = "README.md"
authors = [
    {name="author", email="user@email.com"},
]
dependencies = [
    "requests[security] >= 2.28",
    "python-somepackage >= 3.0.0"
]

[project.scripts]
alias= "script.__main__:main"
```

I am installing the project with *pip*: `python3 -m pip install -e .`. However, whenever I try to run a script within my project, it fails on the import statement:

```py
import python_somepackage
```

with the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/Projects/my-project/src/subproj/some_script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import python_somepackage
  File "/home/username/Projects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/python_somepackage/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from python_somepackage.api_client import ApiClient
  File "/home/username/Projects/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/python_somepackage/api_client.py", line 29, in <module>
    import frozendict
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frozendict'
```

I would have expected that `frozendict` would also be installed since it is a dependency of `python-somepackage`. Maybe I am misunderstanding here. Do I need to have a `requirements.txt`? If so, then what is the point of the `dependencies` key in the `pyproject.toml` file?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the dependencies of your dependencies should be installed. No, you do not need a `requirements.txt` file. It seems to me like there is something else at play here... -- Can we see the package metadata for `python-somepackage`? Maybe this is where the issue is.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, anyone fixed this?

Comment: As @sinoroc said, I also believe the problem is with `python-somepackage`

Comment: I have the same problem, but I also have a setup.py file which might be complicating things. One possible culprit here could be the version of setuptools, however, since I think support for pyproject.toml is only available in later version of it (maybe >= 61?).