# Unable to run python project. `__main__` module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x

I cloned a git repository that I would like to run, the project folder structure is shown bellow.

[image]

I installed the dependencies using,

`python3 -m pip install -e .`

And when I tried to run the package using python,

`python pyfhirsdc`

I get the following error,

`D:\pyfhirsdc\venv\Scripts\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'D:\\pyfhirsdc\\pyfhirsdc'`

I'm new to using `pyproject.toml` files, how can I fix this isse?

Comment: Are you sure it's intended to be run as a standalone command, rather than being imported in other projects?

Comment: No I'm not sure it's meant to run as a standalone command, but when I tried to run the `main.py` I get an error saying dependency is not found.

Similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75819017/pyproject-toml-is-not-installing-my-package-dependencies

How can I solve this? @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're using this repository: https://github.com/SwissTPH/pyfhirsdc

I'm not super familiar with the structure of this repo, but after messing around a bit I figured out a workaround.

You can run this in Git Bash or a linux shell:

```bash
git clone https://github.com/SwissTPH/pyfhirsdc.git

# rename to "__main__" so it's recognized by Python
mv pyfhirsdc/main.py pyfhirsdc/__main__.py

# fix syntax warning
sed -i "s/is not 'id'/!= 'id'/g" pyfhirsdc/pyfhirsdc/converters/planDefinitionConverter.py

# install all dependencies
python3 -m pip install setuptools wheel pandas openpyxl fhir.resources pydantic validators odfpy ocldev requests-toolbelt jsonpath-ng textile fhirpathpy

echo "running pyfhirsdc module with 'help' flag"
python3 pyfhirsdc --help
# expected output:  -c / --conf config_file_path
#                   -o to generate fhir ressoruces
#                   -h / --help to generate this message
#                   -b to bundle the fhir ressource int the output path
#                   -l to build the library with cql in base64
#                   --anthro to generate the antro code system from tsv files
```

someone who has more experience with `pyproject.toml` and the `.egg-info` directory might be able to give better advice :)

Comment: I think I fixed the issue by changing the pyproject.toml structure. So there is no need to install all the dependencies one at  a time

Comment: glad you were able to figure it out!